# Would a better videocard make Ubuntu UI faster (specifically using gvim)?

Tags: video, performance, gui

I have Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity and an Nvidia 7600GS (it has 256Mb memory on board). My resolution is 2560x1440.

I work a lot in `gVim` and the overall experience is that it is slow. For example, it takes long time to switch a tab (especially, if there are many of them). Or, if the screen is scrolled down, it obviously lags.

When I lowered the resolution, this sluggishness disappeared. So, my question is, would a better videocard help here?

Comment: I think you've really answered your own question - you need a much better card - I found this forum entry that may guide you... http://www.overclock.net/t/835863/best-gpu-for-high-resolution-2560-x-1440

Answer (score 2):

From what you say the problem seems to be that window composition is making your system slow at high resolutions.

Do a quick test, run Unity2D instead of Unity3D and check how sluggish it is.

If it is then probably your system also should get an upgrade (RAM, a faster hard-disk or if possible a faster CPU).

If the its not sluggish anymore then a new graphics card would definitely help.

Comment: I ran Unity 2d, gVim is less sluggish, yeah. Thanks.

Comment: That is the fastest way you can check how much your graphics are slowing down your system.